# Magento Flat Category Table contains incorrect data (even after reindexing)

Tags: magento2, database, reindex

After migrating M1.9 Data to M2.2.5, I've noticed an issue with updating Category Information. I imported both Categories and Products together, but only Categories are affected.

**Issue**

If I go into an imported category, I can change any of the values. However, the changes aren't reflected on the frontend.

**Initial Tests**

- If I add a new category to an imported category, all changes I make show just fine on the frontend.
- I've done the obvious like Clear Cache/Reindex/Enable and Disable Flat Tables but it doesn't make a difference.

**What I discovered**

I did a deep dive into the DB. I discovered that all of the `catalog_category_` tables are being updated correctly. However, the `catalog_category_flat_store_1` remains incorrect **ever after reindexing**. So, I then decided to TRUNCATE the table and reindex Magento. After reindexing, the table truncated table is re-populated with the old values again.

I have no idea where this old data is being pulled from to re-populate the table. Plus, Magento shouldn't even be pulling from the table because 'Use Flat Catalog Category' is set to 'No'.

Thoughts?

**Update 1**

After some more digging around in the DB, I discovered that the `catalog_category_` tables are in-fact incorrect. I'm running a single-store setup. However, there are duplicate entries under both `store_id=0` and `store_id=1`. I can see that the values I change in the backend of Magento affect `store_id=1` but Frontend & Flat Category are pulling from `store_id=0`.

Interestingly enough the Test Category I manually created after the import is showing as `store_id=0`. So it looks like Magento is looking all the table entries, but prioritising any Category with `store_id=1` data if it finds it.

**Update 2**

Figured I'd try `Stores` > `Configuration` > `General` > `General` > `Single-Store Mode = Yes`. No noticable changes.